# Disable Material input when received an update from API

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I have a md-input on the component that is two way bound to the object that is filled from rest api call. Based on the response from API I would like to enable it or disable. Right now I have following:

```
        <input type="text"
               mdInput
               [(ngModel)]="test.Price"
               placeholder="Price"
               [disabled]="getDisabledValueForInputs()">

enableInputs(): boolean {
    return (typeof this.test=== 'undefined') 
    || 
    (this.test.Id === null) 
    || 
    (this.test.Id < 1);
  }

  getDisabledValueForInputs() {
    return this.enableInputs() ? null : true;
  }
```

Apparently this function evaluation runs only once on the page render so I am wondering if there is an easy way to access such input box from the subscription to the api call other that use document.getElementById or this is the only way?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What exactly are you trying to do? If you mean you want to change the value of the input after the http calls subscription, why cant you just update the value of `test` in your subscription?

Comment: do you see the input field getting populated after the api call?

Comment: Yes, it is getting populated but is not getting enabled or disabled as it should. I have the same condition to disable autocomplete fields in the subscribe for api call and it works as it should. I wonder if in that function that disables autocomplete I can disable input boxes as well

Comment: I tried to make a demo, and it seems to me that it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2gvbuj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts